# data entry forms show #error in most columns of a previous record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, adodb

I have a 2010 MS Access Application that ran fine until importing into MS Access 2013. Now all the data entry forms show `#Error` in most columns of a previous record when inserting a new record. The Forms use ADODB.Recordsets. The `#Error` persists until clicking on each field where it reverts to original data.

Before Vendor Update of a New Record

```
RowID    Vendor    Ticket
1        DUFFERIN  12345
2        LAFARGE   54321
3        MILTON
```

After Vendor Update

```
RowID    Vendor    Ticket
1        DUFFERIN  12345
3        #ERROR    #ERROR
3        MILTON    123
```

My Connection string:

```vb
ConnectADO = "Data Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" & _
";Data Source=" & TMServerName & _
";Initial Catalog=" & TMDatabaseName & _
";Persist Security Info=False " & _
";user id=" & TMUserName & _
";password=" & TMPassword

Cn.Provider = "MSDataShape"
Cn.CommandTimeout = 120
Cn.ConnectionString = ConnectADO
Cn.Open
```

My Cursor Set-up

```vb
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = LockType
rs.ActiveConnection = Cn
rs.Open Sql
```

Comment: The code post didn't hold its format. Before vendor update and after vendor update are tables three columns wide and three records down.

Comment: I Reduced the app to a single form with RowID, Vendor And Ticket Fields. I Added the open connection function and the open record set function Called it from the on load event of the form. Data shows up but on insert behavior persists. Dll calls are just the four normal and ADO6.1. MSAcces2013 is the 32bit version. I am just going out of my mind.

Comment: What do you mean by 'importing into MS Access 2013'? Should not have to import 2010 db into 2013. Access 2013 should be able to run db created with 2013 without any import, just open the 2010 file.

Comment: If you want to clean a corrupted Access database and rid it of hidden temp queries and such. Import its objects into a fresh database. It is more thorough than compact and repair. Even the code comes across decompiled and needs to be recompiled. A tip every Access developer can use.

Comment: LockType is adLockOptimistic

Comment: Its been six days. I have not received one answer from here or Microsoft MSDN Forum or the Microsoft community Forum. I can't possible be the only one with this problem. I will let it hang out for another week and then I will answer this question with a DAO rebuild required for all data insert forms (A truly dismal outlook as jet sql and t-sql are not the same and I have hundreds of sql statements.).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.

If the ADO Active Connection is open when the forms insert occurs, the `#Error` behavior occurs. If the connection is closed everything is good. Inserts and updates still happen. Therefore, close the connection as soon as possible. I did it like this (the `Cnn.RecordsetOpen` function is custom and has a `connection.open` statement in it before the ADODB recordset open statement).

```vb
'FORM LOAD EVENT
Sub load
On Error Goto Standard_Err
    Dim TSQL As String
    Set Me.Recordset = Cnn.RecordsetOpen(SQL)
Standard_Exit:
    Cnn.connection.close
    Exit Sub
Standard_Err:
    Msgbox err.description
    Resume Standard_Exit
End sub
```